# Fail to deploy project on google app engine

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, deployment

I am attempting to deploy a Java project given from University to the Google Cloud Platform using the "mvn package appengine:deploy -Dapp.deploy.projectId=<id-da-aplicação> -Dapp.deploy.version=".However, I encountered the following error message[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAqmv.png), and the enviroment informations  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2D8b.png),[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BevPt.png),[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miFum.png).

I have attempted various methods to resolve the issue, including running the commands $ gcloud auth login and $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT. However, despite these efforts, I have not been able to deploy the application successfully on Google Cloud Platform. It's worth noting that the application deploys without any issues when run locally.